# Script-Fu giving me "Illegal Function"

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

this is my first script-fu for gimp and it gives me "illegal function" when i try to execute it there.

```
(define
    (
        script-fu-c64ize
        filename
        width
        height
    )
    (let*
        (
            (image 0)
        )
        (image (gimp-file-load 1 filename filename))
        (gimp-image-scale-full image width height 2)
        (gimp-image-scale-full image (/ width 2) height 0)
        (gimp-image-convert-indexed image 1 4 16 FALSE FALSE "C64")
        (gimp-image-scale-full image (* 4 width) (* 4 height) 0)
        (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
        (gimp-file-save 1 image drawable filename filename)
        (gimp-image-delete image)
    )
)
```

maybe someone more experienced can spot the error and i feel i missed something fundamental (or it's just a stupid mistake). i'm still struggling with the docs.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
(image (gimp-file-load 1 filename filename))
```

you're calling `image` as a function, but immediately before, it is bound to a number.  Since numbers aren't functions, this will result in an error.

I'm not familiar with Script-fu, but if I were to guess, I'd replace the `(image 0)` binding form with the one above.

Comment: oh yes, i think you just nailed it. i didn't get this right. i thought i was setting image in the second occurence but you are right, i am calling it as a function. i should use set! or put it into the variable definition part. i'll try it, thanks a ton!

Comment: yes, that was it. thanks again! i have some type error left, but i'll deal with that eventually.